# Agrupar elementos similares de uma Array em PHP

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para minha empresa onde preciso agrupar elementos de uma array que tenham valores em comum. Meu array é o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ALDREYACI
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 22
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ALDREYACI
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 53
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => BRENDAACI
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 6
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => BRENDAACI
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 10
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINE
            [strMotivo] => NATE
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => Não Localizado
            [qtde] => 5
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => NATE
            [qtde] => 177
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => OCUP
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 106
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => Recado
            [qtde] => 218
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => Sem Identificação
            [qtde] => 12
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => ELAINEACI
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => FALE
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => Não Localizado
            [qtde] => 922
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => NATE
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 241
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => Recado
            [qtde] => 444
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => JHONATANAC
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 226
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => MONIQUEACI
            [strMotivo] => FALE
            [qtde] => 2
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => MONIQUEACI
            [strMotivo] => Não Localizado
            [qtde] => 149
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => MONIQUEACI
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 100
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => MONIQUEACI
            [strMotivo] => Recado
            [qtde] => 211
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => MONIQUEACI
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 83
        )

    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => ENEG
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [24] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => FALE
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [25] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => Não Localizado
            [qtde] => 765
        )

    [26] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 221
        )

    [27] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => Recado
            [qtde] => 394
        )

    [28] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => Sem Identificação
            [qtde] => 2
        )

    [29] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => RAFAELACI
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 403
        )

    [30] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => ENEG
            [qtde] => 2
        )

    [31] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => FALE
            [qtde] => 1
        )

    [32] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => LIGD
            [qtde] => 7
        )

    [33] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => Não Localizado
            [qtde] => 962
        )

    [34] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => Promessa de Pagamento
            [qtde] => 372
        )

    [35] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => Recado
            [qtde] => 606
        )

    [36] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => TELM
            [qtde] => 3
        )

    [37] => stdClass Object
        (
            [strRespAciona] => TAMILLESAC
            [strMotivo] => Texto
            [qtde] => 280
        )

)
```

Preciso agrupar os itens pela chave `strRespAciona`, para que fique similar a isso:

```
[ALDREYACI]=> 
(
        ['Promessa de Pagamento'] => 22
        ['Texto']=> 53
)
```

Qual é a melhor maneira de obter um resultado similar ao esperado?

Edit: Existem mais algumas informações que eu tenho para trabalhar.
Juntamente com essa array, eu recebo outras duas: uma com todos os valores possíveis da chave `strMotivo` e outra com todos os valores possíveis da chave `strRespAciona`. Os valores possíveis para a chave `strRespAciona` são:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BRENDAACI
    [1] => MONIQUEACI
    [2] => ELAINEACI
    [3] => ELAINE
    [4] => JHONATANAC
    [5] => TAMILLESAC
    [6] => RAFAELACI
    [7] => ALDREYACI
)
```

E os valores possíveis para a chave `strMotivo` são:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ENEG
    [1] => FALE
    [2] => LIGD
    [3] => Não Localizado
    [4] => NATE
    [5] => OCUP
    [6] => Promessa de Pagamento
    [7] => Recado
    [8] => Sem Identificação
    [9] => TELM
    [10] => Texto
)
```

Até agora, tenho esse código:

```
            $data = $http_response->data;
            $motivos = $http_response->motivos;
            $agentes = $http_response->agentes;

            $data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);

            $json = [];

            for ($a = 0; $a < count($agentes); $a++) {
                $json[$a]['nome'] = $agentes[$a];
                for ($m = 0; $m < count($motivos); $m++) {
                    for ($d = 0; $d < count($data); $d++) {
                        if ($agentes[$a] == $data[$d]['strMotivo']) {
                            $json[$a][$motivos[$m]] = $data[$d]['qtde'];
                        } else {
                            $json[$a][$motivos[$m]] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As variáveis $data, $motivos e $agentes recebem dados da API da aplicação, que por sua vez as extrai do banco de dados da empresa. Esse é o resultado atual do código acima:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => TAMILLESAC
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => JHONATANAC
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nome] => ELAINE
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nome] => BRENDAACI
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [nome] => MONIQUEACI
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [nome] => ELAINEACI
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [nome] => RAFAELACI
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [nome] => ALDREYACI
            [ENEG] => 0
            [FALE] => 0
            [LIGD] => 0
            [Não Localizado] => 0
            [NATE] => 0
            [OCUP] => 0
            [Promessa de Pagamento] => 0
            [Recado] => 0
            [Sem Identificação] => 0
            [TELM] => 0
            [Texto] => 0
        )

)
```

Enquanto o esperado é que as chaves onde hajam correspondência na primeira array de minha dúvida tenham os valores correspondentes à elas e os demais valores sejam preenchidos com zero.

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Se pede a melhor forma, acredito que já atingiu o resultado esperado. Se não, qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Acredito que me expressei mal. Eu consigo chegar quase onde preciso. Consigo agrupar as chaves, porém não as quantidades.

A dificuldade é em justamente agrupar todas essas informações da maneira como preciso.

Comment: Então adicione esse código à pergunta, assim não teremos que partir do zero.

Comment: Adicionei mais informações à pergunta, agora acredito que está mais completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseado no seu cenário, poderia ser algo como

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array( "strRespAciona" => "mauro", 2 ),
    array( "strRespAciona" => "mauro", 1 ),
    array( "strRespAciona" => "ellaa", 3 )
);

$data = [];

foreach($array as $elm){
    $data[ array_shift($elm) ][] = $elm;
}

print_r($data); //resultado abaixo
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [mauro] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [ellaa] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

### Resumo

Para fazer o agrupamento dos dados, é preciso iterar o array para obter os elementos `$elm`; na linha `$data[ array_shift($elm) ][] = $elm;` o `array_shift` é o responsavel por agrupar corretamente os dados iguais  (remove os elementos iguais, mantendo apenas um e os readiciona a variavel `$data`).

Comment: Aparentemente seu código pode solucionar meu problema, mas pode me explicar como ele funciona?

Comment: No fim das contas foi após ver o seu código que consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado!